# I have problems when submitting data from an RSS in my App

Tags: java, android, android-studio

First of all I apologize for the translation, I speak Spanish.

*My problem is the following:*
I use the RSS of my own website to show data in my App, the bad thing is that they do not show up immediately, I need you to do it as it is necessary.

I think the problem may be in the **XMLParser class**:

```
public class XMLParser {

private URL url;
private Context contextor;

public XMLParser(String url) {
    try {
        this.url = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public void parse() {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = builder.parse(this.url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList itema = root.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Node item = itema.item(i);
            NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
            for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
                Node property = properties.item(j);
                String name = property.getNodeName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")) {
                    Log.i("XMLParser", "GUARDO " + property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    int star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg0\">"));
                    int fiinal = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("</table>"));
                    String cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    MyBus.setDomincal(cadena);

                    star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg1\">"));
                    String parteCadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star));
                    fiinal = parteCadena.indexOf("</table>");
                    cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    Log.i("XMLParser", "GUARDO " + url);
                    Log.i("XMLParser", "GUARDO " + cadena);
                    //Log.i("XMLParser", "GUARDO " + MyBus.getIntermedio());
                    MyBus.setIntermedio(cadena);

                    star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg2\">"));
                    parteCadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star));
                    fiinal = parteCadena.indexOf("</table>");
                    cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    MyBus.setZodiacal(cadena);

                    star = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().indexOf("<table class=\"tg3\">"));
                    parteCadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star));
                    fiinal = parteCadena.indexOf("</table>");
                    cadena = (property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().substring(star, star+fiinal+8));
                    MyBus.setExtraordinario(cadena);

                    //MyBus.setSeguro(1);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //MyBus.setSeguro(1);

        //Esto solo es para lanzar un error y para que la app haga un cierre forsozo
        //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}}
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong, because when I check the link in the browser it is updated. Please, if someone can help me, I would really appreciate it.

An example would be: on the website I create a post or simply edit one, I change certain data that I have or there, let's say it said 'red' but now I edited it and put it 'blue'. In the link that I see of the RSS in the browser appears updated, but if I go to my app keeps saying red or does not appear the new post that I created until several hours later or the next day, and that is wrong because the information given my application must be updated every so often and it does not do me any good to do it many hours later.

At first I thought it could be the webview cache but the problem comes before it was shown in that webview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error or problem, specifically? It would also be nice to translate your comment in the exception block, if that is supposed to be the explanation.

Comment: I added an example. I hope you understand me :(

Comment: I can't believe that nobody wants to help me T_T